# Nginx Configuration Issue with ssl and non-ssl

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have two sites and I'd like to publish over https, whereas for sub-domains, I'd like to publish over http. My problem is that the publishing fails for sub-domains.

https://www.my-domain.com // it's working

http://crm.my-domain.com  // not working (ssl blocking)

How should be my configuration file?

Current confgiuration file:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.my-domain.com;

    ssl_certificate     /var/www/my-domain/server/config/certificates/www_my-domain_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/my-domain/server/config/certificates/www_my-domain_com_nokey.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-domain.com my-domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.my-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name my-domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.my-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name crm.my-domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/crm.my-domain.com.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *ssl blocking* mean? Have you tested the configuration using `nginx -T` and have you ever used HTTP Strict Transport Security on this domain?

Comment: When I testing with Chrome got the this message "Your connection is not private" If I testing with firefox site opened but redirect to https://crm.my-domain.com

Comment: As @RichardSmith asked, have you ever used HSTS? If HSTS was previously configured with the 'includeSubDomains' flag, that would cause the subdomains to break over http.

Comment: No, I did not use HSTS. Where and how can I use it?